# Forcing decimal guide with Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, grids

I'm trying to create a Bootstrap grid. But on 1170 width, each column is 97.5 wide, so I will need to create decimal guides.

But when I add a guide with the "add new guide" tool, it always round up my numbers! For instance if I put 42.5, it will render 43px! But I still can move the guide by hand to 42.5 afterwards... it makes no sense.

Does anyone have any insight as to how can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better solution, but a quick workaround is to set your units to Points instead of Pixels since 1 Point = 1 Pixel. Right click on your Ruler to quickly accomplish this.

With Points as your units, you'll be able to specify decimals for the New Guide... command. After you place them you can of course switch your Document Unit back to pixels and the guides will remain in place.

[image: Photoshop Screenshot]

Comment: interesting I didnt think of that. The only problem is, if I want to share my grid using a .atn file (action sequence), the user will have to switch his rule to Points unit or it will not work correctly. Or maybe I can add that option switch in the script, I'll have to take a look

Comment: @topleft you can absolutely set that within an action sequence. Editing the  Rules Unit within Units & Rules Preferences is logged while recording an action: http://i.imgur.com/451KC7X.png